# c++ running time in milliseconds

Tags: c++

```
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    double time1 = 0;
    t1 = clock();
    bubbleSort(data, n);
    t2 = clock();
    time1 = difftime(t2,t1);
    cout<<"Bubble Sort: \n";
    for (int y = 0; y<n; y++)
    {
        cout<<data[y]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Algorithm Runtime is: "<<time1<<" milliseconds.";
}
```

I'm trying to get the running time in milliseconds but I what always get is 0. I only get running time when I input 1000+ random numbers. What I want to get is the running time of low numbers. Can anyone help me.

I try all the other ways I can see in this forum, but it seems not working to me. Maybe I'm doing it in wrong way.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: There's a good chance the code takes only a fraction of milliseconds to run. You should run it in a loop, measure and take the average (in microseconds).

Comment: @ForEveR my prof. said that it calculate the difference of time between t2 and t1.

Comment: The number of ticks between the first and second call of clock are probably much lower than you are expecting.

Comment: @A.Rvyn put the initialization of the data and  call to `bubbleSort` inside a `for` loop , do the `clock` timing calls only before and after the call to `bubbleSort` and then sum up the differences between `t1` and `t2` and after the loop has completed divide by the number of iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So to sort things out - [difftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) takes two `time_t`parameters each of which represent a measurement of current time in seconds since the epoch. [clock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) however gives a number of CPU time that is not seconds. As  the man page states:

> The value returned is the CPU time used so far as a clock_t; to get the number of seconds used, divide by CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

So you are clearly using these functions in a wrong way.

That being said it is also important to ensure the code runs long enough that it actually can be measured and that the running time is not smaller than the resolution of the time metric you are using. What you could do is simply subtract the values returned from `clock()` and divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` ([example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/CPU-Time.html)). If that still gives zero then run the algorithm in a loop.

Comment: Thank you sir. The example really helped me.

Comment: @A.Rvyn you are welcome. Btw, if an algorithm is the only thing that the program contains you can also use the time command (http://linux.die.net/man/1/time)  that runs a program and prints out the times. But if you have to measure the time from inside the code this won't help.

Answer (score 6):

you can make a time measurement that is far more accurate. (nanoseconds).
It needs C++11 to compile.

Example:

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

{

    auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    bubbleSort(data, n);
    auto t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<int64_t,nano> elapsed = t2 - t1; //if you want milliseconds you should use: std::chrono::duration<double,milli>

    cout << "Bubble Sort: \n";
    for (int y = 0; y<n; y++) {
        cout << data[y] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Algorithm Runtime is: " << elapsed.count() << " nanoseconds.";

}
```

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: A more accurate time measurement is indeed theoretically possible.  But it won't be, in real life, if you're receiving substantially fewer ticks than you think you are.  A few years ago I also naively assumed that nanosecond precision time interval from chrono would be accurate.  Unfortunately they weren't, though, which made that first attempt at benchmarking C++ code unsuccessful.  Another consideration is that the implementation of stuff from time.h is likely a lot more mature and therefore likely less buggy, than the chrono implementation code itself.